# How to return a struct in xv6 syscalls?

Tags: c, struct, system-calls, xv6

I am currently testing xv6 and implemented a new syscall.

As far as I can see, all syscalls in xv6 return an int. 
Is this needed and why?

Because I would like to return a C struct.

Is this possible? 
What would I have to do, to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from the syscalls is stored in the `eax` register.

As seen in the [source](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/xv6/blob/ff2783442ea2801a4bf6c76f198f36a6e985e7dd/syscall.c#L133):

```
proc->tf->eax = syscalls[num]();
```

This means that the return value will always be a single 32-bit value.

The type of the functions for system call handlers is also defined as returning `int` and taking no arguments:

```
static int (*syscalls[])(void)
```

The correct way to return a struct in this situation is to pass a user-space pointer to as a syscall argument. After verifying that it's valid, it will store the struct data at that pointer. Note that since the syscall handler itself takes no arguments, you have to use the argument getters like `argptr`, which handles validity checking for you.

Comment: I would add that system calls like this should take _two_ arguments for the struct to be returned: the pointer you mention, and also the expected size of the struct. This is not critical for a homework exercise, but in a production OS you have to worry about `sizeof(T)` not matching up between user space and the kernel (for several different reasons).

Comment: The other syscalls are capable of handling multiple arguments, so you'd do that in the same way they do, by using those argument getters. However, if you assume that the size might not line up, how would you know that the fields in the struct are all in the correct locations. While I'm not super familiar with how other operating systems handle this, I'd assume that it's up to the userspace to conform to the specifications of the operating system.

Comment: If you're assuming that the fields will all be in the same place and have the same size, but trailing padding on the struct might be present, then I can only really see that being an issue if the size in the OS is greater than the size in userspace, and if the compiler were to mess with the contents of that padding for some reason, or if the struct is right at the edge of the process's address space.

Comment: The most common case where this comes up in production is that the syscall has grown new features since it was introduced, so there are more fields in the OS's version of the struct than an old user-space binary expects.  With the size argument, the kernel can avoid writing the fields beyond the end of the old binary's allocation.

Comment: Very true. Either way, it's just another argument. How you choose to implement things is up to you.